# #inf c++ visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I came across question in calculating the sum of a double. When I set iteration to 100000, the function Asian_call_MC still return a number. However, when I set iteration to around 500000 and above, it begin to return 1.#INF. Can someone tell me why it happens and how to solve it? I am using visual studio 2013 to write c++ code.

```
double Avg_Price(double init_p, double impl_vol, double drift, int step, double deltasqrt)
{
//Calculate the average price of one sample path
//delta  = T/ step
//drift = (risk_free - div_y - impl_vol*impl_vol / 2)*(T / step)
double Sa = 0.0;
double St = init_p;

for (int i = 0; i < step; i++)
{
    St = St*exp(drift + impl_vol*deltasqrt*normal_gen());
    //Sa = Sa * i / (i + 1) + St / (i + 1);
    Sa += St;
}
Sa = Sa / double(step);
return Sa;
}


double Asian_call_MC(double strike_p, double T, double init_p, double impl_vol, double risk_free, double div_y, int iter, int step)
{
//Calculate constants in advance to reduce computation time
double drift = (risk_free - div_y - impl_vol*impl_vol / 2)*double(T / step);
double deltasqrt = sqrt(double(T / step));


//Generate x1, average x and y
double cur_p = Avg_Price(init_p,impl_vol,drift,step,deltasqrt);
double pay_o=0.0;
double x = max(cur_p - strike_p,0.0);
//double y = pow(x, 2.0);


//Generate x2 to xn
for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++)
{
    cur_p = Avg_Price(init_p, impl_vol, drift, step, deltasqrt);
    x = max(cur_p - strike_p,0.0);
    //double q = double(i) / double(i + 1);
    //pay_o = pay_o *i/(i+1) + x / (i + 1);
    pay_o += x;
    //y = (1 - (1 / (i + 1)))*y + x*x / (i + 1);
}
//pay_o = pay_o / double(iter);
//stdev = sqrt((y - pow(pay_o , 2)) / (iter - 1));
//return pay_o*exp(-risk_free*T) ;
return pay_o;
}
```

Comment: What does `normal_gen` return?  What's the number you get with 100000 iterations?

Comment: normal_gen generate a normally distributed number with mean 0 and variance 1. The sum is about 800000 when I set the iteration to 100000.

Comment: So it can return a "large" number, then, and isn't bounded.  At some point one of your iterations is getting a large enough value there that, when combined with the values for drift, impl_vol, and deltasqrt, results in an overflow (any value over around 710).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to compute mean values.  The the way most people learn to calculate a mean is to sum up all the values, then divide the sum by the number of values which contributed to the sum.

This method has a few problems associated with it -- for example, adding many values together might give a sum which is too large for the variable holding it.

Another technique is often used, which accumulates a "running" mean instead of a sum.  The running mean's value is always the mean value for all samples already accumulated, so it never blows up into an overflow (floating-point infinity) value (except when one of the accumulated samples was infinity).

The example below demonstrates how to calculate a running mean.  It also calculates the sum and shows how sum/count compares to the running mean (to show that they are the same -- I haven't let it run long enough to overflow the sum).

The example uses the C-Library rand(), for demonstration purposes -- I just needed something to calculate mean values from.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
        srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(0)));

        double count = 0;
        double running_mean = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        auto start = time(0);
        auto end = start + 5;
        while(time(0) < end) {
            double sample = rand();
            count += 1;
            running_mean += (sample - running_mean)/count;
            sum += sample;
        }

        std::cout << std::setprecision(12);
        std::cout << "running mean:" << running_mean << "  count:" << count << '\n';
        double sum_mean = sum / count;
        std::cout << "sum:" << sum << "  sum/count:" << sum_mean << '\n';
}
```

**Edit:** He already tried this -- 
the technique appeared in commented-out lines that I missed in the OP's code

Unlike computing the average value by accumulating a grand sum, the running mean technique cannot simply overflow at some point.  So knowing that he already tried this and that it didn't help the problem, the probable cause becomes that one of the iteration's terms is, itself INF.  As soon as a single INF term is added, the accumulated sum or mean will become INF and stay INF.

The most likely section of code was `normal_gen()` used inside the argument for a call to the `exp` function.  The name `normal_gen()` sounds like a source of Normally-distributed random values.  The usual implementation employs a Box–Muller transform, which cannot produce values over about 7 standard-deviations away from the mean.  So if a Box-Muller generator was causing the INF, it would probably occur within fewer iterations than reported.  However, more advanced generators can produce more extreme values -- ideally a Normal distribution has a nonzero probability of producing **any** finite real value.

If a randomly large Normal sample is what was causing the problem, its correlation with increased iteration count would not be that more iterations inflate the sum, to the point of overflowing by adding more values -- it would be that more iterations gave the program a better chance to hit an unlikely random value which would result in an INF term.

Comment: I used that technique in the commented out part of my code. However it returns the same thing.

Comment: Ah, I see now, I didn't recognize it at first: `Sa = Sa * i / (i + 1) + St / (i + 1);`  You should stay with that -- there is also a matter of numeric stability which is an improvement over the final division.

Comment: Since it looks like the sum is not naturally overflowing, I would start to suspect one of its terms being INF -- does `normal_gen` generate random values from a normal distribution?  Some versions of such a generator will occasionally generate very large (negative or positive) values, and in your code, this value is part of an argument to `exp`, which goes big real fast, so it might not be a matter of accumulating too large of a sum during many iterations, but a matter of many iterations making it more probable that an INF value is randomly generated and added to the sum.

Comment: I think it is indeed the issue of normal random number generator. Once I changed the generator, it solves the issue. The old generator just generated the same sequence of "random number" every time. There must be one number in that sequence exploded. Thank you very much!@Christopher Oicles

Comment: Yay!  I guess my comment was the real answer, so I'll have to add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you ane increasing the number of iterations, you are increasing the value of the sum. At some point, the value overflows what is possible to contain within a `double`, thus returning the `1.#INF` value that represents infinity as what you calculated. It does this because the calculated value is greater than what can be held in a couple.

To fix the problem, you'll need to change the variable that you're holding the sum with to something that can hold a greater number than a `double`. The starting point would be using a `long double`.

Another option would be to build in some of the logic that you have after the `for` loop into it so you're dealing with smaller numbers. How to do this will vary depending on what exactly you're string to calculate.

Comment: On some systems a `long double` has the same precision as a `double` so that may not gain you anything.

Comment: When I set the iteration to 100000, the sum is a number around 800000. It is ought to be a number around 8000000 when I set the iteration to 1000000. Do you think there are any other possible reasons?

Comment: in MSVC (which the OP is using) `long double` is exactly the same as `double`

Answer (score 0):

You're overflowing what double can hold. INF is short for infinity, which is the error code you get when you overflow a floating point.

Long double may or may not help depending on your compiler. In Microsoft C++ I believe long double and double are both 64 bits, so no luck there.

Check out Boost multiprecision library, it has larger types, if you really need something that big and can't redo your math. I see you're multiplying a bunch and then dividing. Can you multiply some, then divide, then multiply some more possibly to save space?

Comment: I have tried dividing and multiplying too. However, it doesn't work neither.